# Sort method with field name passed in

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, but I am trying to have a generic sort method I can pass to my sorts. At the moment, I have a poor implementation, because the objects I sort may have different fields I want to sort on:

```
export function sortByName( a, b ) {
    if ( a.name < b.name ){
        return -1;
    }
    if ( a.name > b.name){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

export function sortByDescription( a, b ) {
    if ( a.description < b.description ){
        return -1;
    }
    if ( a.description > b.description){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to create a method that takes extra parameters. FieldName, and Desc (Bool). So that I can specify the field in the object, and the direction.

Something like:

```
export function sortByField( a, b, fieldName, isDesc ) {
    if ( a.[fieldName] < b.[fieldName] ){
        return -1;
    }
    if ( a.[fieldName] > b.[fieldName]){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And then some logic to handle the isDesc. But then the sort call fails as it doesn't pass those fields.

```
this.state.templates.sort(sortByDescription).map(template => (
```

I'm not sure how to add the extra parameters. Sort seems to accept a method with 2 parameters only. Is there a way to achieve a single generic method, that allows sorting on a specific field on the objects being sorted?

Maybe I cannot use `.sort`, and need to create my own version of sort?

Comment: try this `a[fieldName]` `b[fieldName]` in function `sortByDescription`

Comment: I think you should delete the dots in the sortByDescription function in lines 2 and 5

Comment: Ah, I can do that, thanks. But how can I get the fieldName in, and the isDesc? I need to pass (a,b,fieldName, isDesc), but not sure how to pass those in. .sort(a,b,'name', 1) - but sort doesn't pass a and b.

Comment: No there is no way that you can get `fieldName` dynamically. Instead you will have to pass it when you call the `fn sortByDescription`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kunal mentioned, just use a[fieldName] and b[fieldName].
Do not pass the function directly as a parameter to sort but instead do something like this

```
    array.sort((a, b) => {
        //possibly some logic here
        sortByDescription(a, b, "myField", true);
    }).map(...
```

Comment: Ah! I see! Perfect! Worked.

Comment: @Craig please mark as accepted answer if it is :)